# How to use callback function with parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, callback, arrow-functions

I have a function, that is returning callback. But meetUid is static on here.

```js
fetchMeetDetails = async (callback) => {

        const meetUid = '1a712f91-974d-4185-9389-f7b1b4edede2';
        const snapshot = await database().ref(`/meets/${meetUid}`).once('value');

        callback(snapshot.val())

    }
```

I want to get meetUid from parameters. like that `fetchMeetDetails = async (callback,meetUid) => {` but I cannot do it. Because we got an error (TypeError : callback is not a function). How can I use this function with callback and parameters ?

Comment: Why are you using a callback at all when you have a promise-based `async` function? Just `return` the result.

Comment: Adding a parameter for it should work just like that. Please show us the code that produces this type error, including the part where you are calling `fetchMeetDetails`.

Comment: That's interesting. The way you pass `callback` as a parameter is unclear thus the compiler complains. Try this `(callback=f=>f, meetUid)`

Comment: It is pretty obvious, isn't it? Can you provide the snippet where you call the `fetchMeetDetails` function? You need to pass a javascript function to `fetchMeetDetails` in order to execute something like `callback(foo)`. `Callback` is just a name convention for javascript function which will be excuted after an async action returns a result (success or error)

Comment: @Bergi My reason for using callback, where componentdidmount is not waiting for a response. Blank data is printed on the screen. So I use callback. 
And I call this function on here => ` componentDidMount() {
        FirebaseDB.fetchMeetDetails((result) => {
            this.setState({
                meet: result
            })
        })}`

Comment: Alright, let me explain the concept in a bit in the answer section for those who might miss this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError : callback is not a function
>   `Type` is the key word here.

Compiler takes the `callback` parameter as anything because of how you declared it first.
*Not a problem.*

Next, compiler meets this `callback(snapshot.val())` and then it gets confused.
*Then it says, "Well, am confused with this `type`. Let me complain!"*

**In such situation, the compiler wants to know the `default` type of that parameter.**

```js
// Since here "callback" is a function, pass "callback" as a default function

(callback=f=>f, ...rest) => {}
```

[It's the same concept when passing "props" to "children" in react](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779233/10849438).