# Do function components have props in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

Can we use props in function components in React, and if then, how?I was trying to do

```
console.log(this.props)
```

above the return function in a function component but it kept giving me errors.

Comment: hi @Salman Ahmed, you use `this` to access props if it is a class based component, otherwise you access directly

Comment: The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) is always a good place to start learning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Passing down props to functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963565/react-passing-down-props-to-functional-components)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You pass the props inside the function component directly (using `props`) like this:

```
function myFunc(props){
  console.log(props.content);
  return <div>{props.content}</div>;
}
```

assuming that the `props` that passes in has element `content`.

To clarify, there is no `this` in function components because they're not classes at all! Instead, you pass in `props` directly into the function.

In fact, it is probably the one of the first things that you learn in React. So if you're new, then I suggest [the tutorial here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this,

the props are passed to the function component as the first argument

```js
export default function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

here read this article it explains everything: https://medium.com/@PhilipAndrews/react-how-to-access-props-in-a-functional-component-6bd4200b9e0b

Answer (score -1):

You can access "this" keyword in class component ... In functional component you can access the props just by calling it as below.

```
import React from 'react'

const Printing=(props)=> {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
export default Printing
```