# How to use a useState function in another component with props?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state, prop

I write a **React.js** note web application where a user can add up to 10 notes.

I use `map()` to iterate the array of notes, and a `useState(1)` hook to update its count (the default number of notes is 1), so I would like to do something like this:

```
  {[...Array(noteCount)].map((_, i) => <Note onUpdateNoteCount={() =>setNoteCount(n => n - 1)} key={i} />)}
```

The thing is that the **Note()** component is inside a **Main()** component which is in the **App()** component, so I want to get the needed values as props of **App()**, and than use them in **Note()**, but can not figure out how and where to put it.

**Thanks!**

> App.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Header from './Header';
  import Main from './Main';
function App () {
  const [noteCount, setNoteCount] = React.useState(1);
  function multiplyNoteComponent () {
    if (noteCount < 20) {
      setNoteCount(n => n + 1)
    }
    else {
      alert('too many notes. remove or combine some of them together!')
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      {[...Array(noteCount)].map((_, i) => <Main onUpdateNoteCount={() =>setNoteCount(n => n - 1)} key={i} />)}

      <button
            style={{left: '5%'}}
          id='addNoteBtn'
          onClick={multiplyNoteComponent}
          title='Add a note'
         >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
  export default App;
```

> Main.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Note from './Note';
function Main () {
    return (
        <main>
            your notes are:
            <Note/>
        </main>
    )
}
    export default Main;
```

> Note.js

```
    import React from 'react';
function Note () {
    return (
        <div> <button title='delete note' onClick={}>X</delete>
            <li>
                <input type='text'/>
            </li>
        </div>
    )
}
    export default Note
```

Edit: the reason I think I need the setNoteCount() function to be used in the Note() component, is for the count down when a note is being deleted (every note has its own delete button).

Comment: You can pass props from App -> Main -> Note like explained here :  
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540647/5427320

Comment: Maybe `App` should pass `Note`s as children to `Main`. I'm not quite following we you are keep track of the *number* of notes. You need to save the text somewhere, right? Why not just have an array of strings?

Comment: @AtifSaddique Thanks, but I think I need to pass the setNoteCount() somehow into Note.js(), don't I? :)

Comment: If you need that `setNoteCount` in your child component, then you can pass the function as prop as well to child component, but I don't think you should pass the overall noteCount set function to individual Note, the parent should handle the set note count.

Comment: I think you should explain a bit more about your needs, what I understand from your question is that you need to pass some props from App.js to Note.js, which can be done by passing props from App.js to Main.js and then from there to Note.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this architecture of the your App.

1. Store the `Notes` array at the `App` level.
2. Add a note using `NoteInput` which adds a notes to your `Notes` array.
3. Map your `Notes` using the `Note` component which takes `onDelete` as a prop from `App` level.
4. Your `App` component should be responsible for storing and delete a note from the state.

In your example, `notesCount` is meant to a derivative state.
i.e it could be derived simply from the `Notes` array (notes.length).

So, rather than storing `notesCount`, I recommend storing notes and deriving count from it.

You could see the working example here :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g19tei

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const NOTES_ALLOWED = 10;

export default function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = React.useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    if (notes.length === NOTES_ALLOWED) {
      alert(`Only ${NOTES_ALLOWED} notes are allowed to be added`)
    } else {
      setNotes([...notes, newNote]);
    }
  }

  function handleDelete(deleteNoteIdx) {
    const newNotes = [...notes];
    // delete the note at the specific index
    newNotes.splice(deleteNoteIdx, 1)
    setNotes(newNotes);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}>
        <p>Your notes are</p>
        {notes.map((note, idx) => ( 
          <Note 
            note={note} 
            onDelete={() => handleDelete(idx)} 
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <NoteInput onAdd={addNote} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Note({ note, onDelete }) {
  return (
    <div>
     <p>{note}
      <button onClick={onDelete}>Delete Note</button>
     </p>
    </div>
  )
}

function NoteInput({ onAdd }) {
  const [note, setNote] = React.useState('');

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const noteToBeSend = note;
    setNote('')
    onAdd(noteToBeSend.trim());
  }

  return (
    <div>
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          value={note}
          onChange={e => setNote(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Add Note</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, your answer + reading the documentations of react props * 5 helped a lot! I just wondered, is a prop that's transferred to a grandchild is a reason to start using Redux?

Comment: In the current scenario of React, there is no need to use Redux though. You could simply use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). The only difference between using Redux and the Context API would be performance is optimized with Redux.