# ReactJS how to pass child component title from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a slick carousel component to display products for different pages, so I need to set its title from parent component: something like `<Component title="Products" />`

Here is the basic structure of my jsx files, can we do it with a simple method like below?

**Parent.jsx:**

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <Component title="Products" />
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

**Component.jsx:**

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <h3>
      {title}
    </h3>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: const Component = (props) => <h3>{ props.title }</h3> will do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Passing down props to functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963565/react-passing-down-props-to-functional-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data from a parent Component to a Child via the [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <Component title="Products" />
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

Component.jsx:

```
const Component = ( props ) => {
  return (
    <h3>
      {props.title}
    </h3>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the title parameter like this

**Destructured parameter**

```
const Component = ({title}) => {
  return (
    <h3>
      {title}
    </h3>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

or like this

**`props` parameter**

```
const Component = (props) => {
  return (
    <h3>
      {props.title}
    </h3>
  );
}

export default Component;
```